# Duplicate list items even when using 'new' keyword

Tags: c#, asp.net

Sorry for asking such a vague question, i'm new to using C# / ASP.NET. When creating randomly generated questions, and storing the question objects within a list through the use of a for loop the same / duplicate question is showing up when I output the questions. I've inspected the list of questions with the debugger, and it shows 10 of the same object.

**Server-side C# Used to populate the list of questions:**

```
private void Populate()
{
    __NumberOfQuestions = 10;
    __Questions = new List<Question>(__NumberOfQuestions);

    for (int i = 0; i < __NumberOfQuestions; i++)
    {
        __Questions.Add(new Question());
    }

    QuestionList.DataSource = __Questions;
    QuestionList.DataBind();
}
```

Question class is avaialable here:
http://pastebin.com/mEArQFHh

**ASP Code used to add the questions to the page:**

```
            <asp:Repeater ID="QuestionList" runat="server">
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <tr>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"__LeftOperand")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"__Operator")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"__RightOperand")%></td>
                        <td><%#DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"__Answer")%></td>
                    </tr>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
```

Output:

9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3
9
SUBTRACT
6
3

Comment: Your implementation of the Random class is wrong.  You might want to research on the correct implementation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you're doing wrong:

1. You create a new `Random` object for each `Question`.
2. Since you don't provide an argument to the `Random` constructor, the default,
   time-based, seed is used. This uses `Environment.TickCount` (though I don't think this is documented specifically), so it has millisecond granularity.
3. Since you construct all of your questions in the same millisecond,
   they'll use the same seed.
4. This means that they'll get the same sequence of random numbers.
5. This means that you get 10 different questions, but all with the
   same values.

The simplest way to fix this is to make your `Random` object `static`, which means it's shared by all of the `Question` objects -- or belongs to the `Question` class, rather than to question instances. This means it'll only be constructed once, and you'll get a sensible sequence of random numbers.

Answer (score 3):

Every question has its own `Random` instance, and they most probably all produce the same values.

When you use the default `Random` constructor, it is [initialized with a seed derived from the system clock](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9.aspx), and if there is such a short time between creating the objects, it might very well be that the system clock value doesn't change between instantiations.

To be exact, `Random` is initialized with [`Environment.TickCount`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.tickcount.aspx) (at least in .NET 4.0), which changes only once every millisecond. That is enough time to create countless of your `Question` objects.

Solution: Make the `Random` field `static`.

Answer (score 1):

If the new Question() is supposed to return a new random question, and you want 10 random questions, i think the "random" function is returning always the same question, so verify the Question Object. The seed of the Random class is always the same?